# Responsive Carousel React material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I am trying to build a music tour website using React material-ui.
I woul like the website to look like this one: https://www.oddfantastic.com/

I am new to React and after looking to libraries such as bootstrap and material-ui and decided to stick to material-ui. Right now I'm stuck on the first page with the sliding images. I tried different ways to obtain the result of the first page of the above website but no luck until now.
I started using grid and cards, and now I am trying grid list. Here is my code:

```
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Grid, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import { Carousel, CarouselSlide } from 'material-ui-carousel'

export default class App extends Component {
pictures = [
    {imagel: './images/radio7-2-1.png', imager: './images/radio7-2-2.png', title: 'r7-2'},
    {imagel: './images/radio7-3-1.png', imager: './images/radio7-3-2.png', title: 'r7-3'},
    {imagel: './images/masterphil-1.png', imager: './images/masterphil-2.png', title: 'mp'},
    {imagel: './images/vito-1.png', imager: './images/vito-2.png', title: 'vito'},
  ];

render () {
    return (
// <Grid container justify="center" spacing={0}>
  /* {[0, 1].map(value => (
    <Grid key={value} item> */
      <Carousel>
        {this.pictures.map(({ imagel, imager, title }) => (
        <CarouselSlide key={title}>
           <GridList cellHeight={160} cols={2}>
             <GridListTile key={title} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
               <img src={imagel} alt={title} />
             </GridListTile>
           </GridList>
          {/* <Card width="100%" key={title}>
            <CardMedia
              image={imagel}
              title={title}
              style={{
              height: 0,
              width: '50%',
              paddingTop: '75%',
              }}
            />
            <CardMedia
              image={imager}
              title={title}
              style={{
              height: 0,
              width: '50%',
              paddingTop: '75%',
              }}
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography>{title}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card> */}
        </CarouselSlide>
        ))}
      </Carousel>

    /* </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid> */

)
}
}
```

Here is the obtained result:
[image]

It looks like all the images appear at the same time.

Since my knowledge is really really limited, I am wondering if I chose the right library. Especially that I couldn't find a material-ui component allowing to achieve what I want.

Any advice or direction would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 26):

The **MUI official doc** consists of an example of using Carousel Effect.

The example can be found [here](https://mui.com/components/steppers/#text-with-carousel-effect)

The demo uses [react-swipeable-views](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views) to create a carousel.

Comment: Well spotted, Prakhar!

Comment: The package "react-swipeable-views" is not compatible with the most recent React versions. The current package (0.14.0) on npm requires React 15.3.0, 16.0.0, or 17.0.0

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel) which is an extendible Carousel UI component using Material-UI. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

Material UI doesn’t have a native Carousel component btw and I find Material UI customization very challenging for beginners. After trying many carousel libraries recently, I found the ant design has the best ready-to-use [carousel](https://ant.design/components/carousel/). The library is developed and maintained by Alibaba group, so you can rely on it better than some small libraries.

Comment: AntD is heavy and slow. You might want to go for a standalone npm lib that does carousel.

Comment: @duduwe will the whole antD library load even if I only import and use carousel?

Comment: @coder you need to make sure tree shaking works by analyzing the output build. If you want to use Carousel alone, I think that would be fine. Just make sure it's only Carousel gets included in your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

if someone still stacked in this, just use this:

```
npm install react-material-ui-carousel --save
you should install also:
npm install @mui/material
npm install @mui/icons-material
npm install @mui/styles

import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';

            <Carousel>
                {
                    this.props.item.images.map( (image, i) => <img key={i} src={image} /> )
                }
            </Carousel>
```